# Use property of type class as parameter

Tags: c#, .net, class

Below I have a class that has a property that's type is of another class:

```
    ParentClass parentClass = new ParentClass();

    public class ParentClass
    {
        public NestedClass nestedClassProperty { get; set; }
    }
```

Below is the class that is used as a property in ParentClass:

```
    public class NestedClass
    {
        public string someProperty { get; set; }
    }
```

How would I pass nestedClassProperty to a method that only accepts properties that are apart of ParentClass? See the below example:

```
    public void method1()
    {
        method2(parentClass.nestedClassProperty);
    }

    public void method2(/* Parameter should accept the nestedClassProperty
                           within ParentClass Note: This method should also                 
                           accept any other property within ParentClass   
                           that's type is of another class. */)
    {
        /* Do something with nestedClassProperty.

           Note: Every class that's nested as a property 
           within ParentClass will have identical properties. */
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just make method2 take a ParentClass as its parameter and check the value of nestedClassProperty?

Comment: Why not just define an interface of what you want. Then make no assumptions about which class impl are actually being passed in? You really ought to not assume what will passed into a public method; otherwise you'll find unit testing difficult if nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Just like any other method signature, the parameter would be of the expected type:

```
public void method2(ParentClass.NestedClass nestedClassObject)
{
    // ...
}
```

For classes nested within another class, the type qualifier is simply `OuterClass.InnerClass`.

**Edit:** If there can be multiple nested classes then you'd need to group them in some way, either as the parameter type or as a type constraint on a generic method.  The nature of being a nested class itself isn't structurally significant to the type system.

Note what you state here:

> Note: Every nested class will have identical properties.

This looks like a job for an interface:

```
public interface INestedClass
{
    // declare the identical members
}
```

Then the nested classes would implement that interface:

```
public class ParentClass
{
    // etc.

    public class NestedClass : INestedClass
    {
        // implement the interface
    }
}
```

The method argument would then be of the interface:

```
public void method2(INestedClass nestedClassObject)
{
    // ...
}
```

The interface itself can also probably be nested like any other class.

Essentially what you're looking for is textbook polymorphism.  Whether or not any given type is nested within another type makes no difference.

Comment: Apologies for not clarifying but 'method2' will need to accept any nested class within ParentClass.

Comment: @Cryptonaut: In that case you'd need to have some common type, such as an interface.  I've updated my answer accordingly.